# Stored Procedure in Report Viewer

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reportviewer

I made a report and added a dataset with a stored procedure but when I try to add columns to the report the only columns that I get are (code-messgeA-messageE-data) as shown in this image

[image: Click Here]

But the columns that are in the stored procedure are not showing and I don't know why.

Comment: Can you be more specific which columns you are trying to add to the report.

Comment: @JunaidSultan There are multiple columns that should come from the stored procedure in the database but these columns are not showing. The columns in the image are showing but they are part of the columns in my stored procedure.

Comment: share your stored procedure.